# How to update gauge needle/value dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to update value/needle of gauge using OUTPUT value of form (having some input fields which are generated dynamically). form is working well. output value is also visible. but needle of gauge is not moving. even, more than half part of needle is also not visible. because i am new to JavaScript, i can't understand what is the issue with it. Can anyone please solve my issue. i will be grateful.

Here is my code

```js
/*code of gauge */
(function () {
      var Needle, arc, arcEndRad, arcStartRad, barWidth, chart, chartInset, degToRad, el, endPadRad, height, i, margin, needle, numSections, padRad, percToDeg, percToRad, percent, radius, ref, sectionIndx, sectionPerc, startPadRad, svg, totalPercent, width;

//calculation for output value
$(document).ready(function() {

  
  $("#Cal").click(function() {

    var stocksVal = 0,
        bondsVal = 0,
        landVal = 0;
        
    $(".fields input").each(function() {
      var idHeading = $(this).attr("id");
      if (idHeading == "Stocks") {
        stocksVal = parseInt(calcVal[idHeading]);
        stocksVal = !isNaN(stocksVal)? stocksVal : 0;
            console.log("calcVal",parseInt(calcVal[idHeading]), idHeading, stocksVal);
      }
      if (idHeading == "Bonds") {
        bondsVal = parseInt(calcVal[idHeading]);
        bondsVal = !isNaN(bondsVal)? bondsVal : 0;
      }
      if (idHeading == "Land") {
        landVal = parseInt($(this).val());
        landVal = !isNaN(landVal)? landVal : 0;
      }
 
    });

   var percent = (stocksVal) + (bondsVal) + (landVal);

 document.getElementById('total').innerText = percent;
    
    if ((percent) > 100) {
    percent = 1.0
  }

  });
});

  $('body').on('keyup', 'input', function(){
  if($(this).val().indexOf("-") !== -1 || $(this).val() == 0){
    if(defaults[$(this).attr('id')]){
     calcVal[$(this).attr('id')] = defaults[$(this).attr('id')]     
    }else{
      calcVal[$(this).attr('id')] = parseInt($(this).val());
    }
  }else{
    calcVal[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
  }
}) 

/* code of gauge */

      barWidth = 60;

      numSections = 3;

      // / 2 for HALF circle
      sectionPerc = [0.1, 0.25, 0.15];

      padRad = 0;

      chartInset = 10;

      // start at 270deg
      totalPercent = . 75;

      el = d3.select('.chart-gauge');

      margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 20 };


      width = el[0][0].offsetWidth - margin.left - margin.right;

      height = width;

      radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

      percToDeg = function (perc) {
        return perc * 360;
      };

      percToRad = function (perc) {
        return degToRad(percToDeg(perc));
      };

      degToRad = function (deg) {
        return deg * Math.PI / 180;
      };

      svg = el.append('svg').attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right).attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

      chart = svg.append('g').attr('transform', `translate(${(width + margin.left) / 2}, ${(height + margin.top) / 2})`);

      // build gauge bg
      for (sectionIndx = i = 1, ref = numSections; 1 <= ref ? i <= ref : i >= ref; sectionIndx = 1 <= ref ? ++i : --i) {
        arcStartRad = percToRad(totalPercent);
        arcEndRad = arcStartRad + percToRad(sectionPerc[sectionIndx-1]);
        totalPercent += sectionPerc[sectionIndx-1];
        startPadRad = 0;
        endPadRad = 0;
        arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius - chartInset).innerRadius(radius - chartInset - barWidth).startAngle(arcStartRad + startPadRad).endAngle(arcEndRad - endPadRad);
        chart.append('path').attr('class', `arc chart-color${sectionIndx}`).attr('d', arc);
      }

      Needle = class Needle {
        constructor(len, radius1) {
          this.len = len;
          this.radius = radius1;
        }

        drawOn(el, perc) {
          el.append('circle').attr('class', 'needle-center').attr('cx', 0).attr('cy', 0).attr('r', this.radius);
          return el.append('path').attr('class', 'needle').attr('d', this.mkCmd(perc));
        }

        animateOn(el, perc) {
          var self;
          self = this;
          return el.transition().delay(500).ease('elastic').duration(3000).selectAll('.needle').tween('progress', function () {
            return function (percentOfPercent) {
              var progress;
              progress = percentOfPercent * perc;
              return d3.select(this).attr('d', self.mkCmd(progress));
            };
          });
        }

        mkCmd(perc) {
          var centerX, centerY, leftX, leftY, rightX, rightY, thetaRad, topX, topY;
          thetaRad = percToRad(perc / 2); // half circle
          centerX = 0;
          centerY = 0;
          topX = centerX - this.len * Math.cos(thetaRad);
          topY = centerY - this.len * Math.sin(thetaRad);
          leftX = centerX - this.radius * Math.cos(thetaRad - Math.PI / 2);
          leftY = centerY - this.radius * Math.sin(thetaRad - Math.PI / 2);
          rightX = centerX - this.radius * Math.cos(thetaRad + Math.PI / 2);
          rightY = centerY - this.radius * Math.sin(thetaRad + Math.PI / 2);
          return `M ${leftX} ${leftY} L ${topX} ${topY} L ${rightX} ${rightY}`;
        }};



      needle = new Needle(140, 15);

      needle.drawOn(chart, 0);

      needle.animateOn(chart, percent);
  
  var percentage = percent*100

if (percentage > 70) {
  rating = 'Good'
  }
  
else if (percentage > 20 && percentage < 70) {
   rating = 'Average' 
  }
  
else {
   rating = 'Bad' 
  } 

percentValue = document.getElementById('percentValue');
percentValue.innerText = rating;

    }).call(this);

 /* code of generating input fields dynamically */ 

let headings = []
const defaults = {Stocks: 100, Bonds: 60};
const calcVal = {};

// appending the created HTML string to the DOM
function initInputs(headingList) {
  jQuery(".fields").append(createInputsHTML(headingList))
}

// the HTMLT template that is going to be appended
// to the DOM
function createInputsHTML(headingList) {
  let html = ''
  headingList.forEach(heading => {
    if (heading !== 'Name') {
      html += `<label for="${heading}">${heading}: </label>`
      html += `<input type="number" id="${heading}">`
      html += '<br>'
    }
  })

  return html
}

// receiving data
// this data arrives later in the app's lifecycle,
// so it's the best to return a Promise object
// that gets resolved (check JS Promise for more information)
function getJSON() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    jQuery.get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.coasilat.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/data-4.txt", function(data) {
      resolve(JSON.parse(data))
    });
  })
}

// processing raw JSON data
function processRawData(data) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const nameData = []
    // creating data array
    // handling multiple sheets
    Object.values(data).forEach((sheet, index) => {
      sheet.forEach((name, i) => {
        nameData.push({ ...name
        })
        // create headings only once
        if (index === 0 && i === 0) {
          Object.keys(name).forEach(item => {
            headings.push(item.trim())
          })
        }
      })
    })
    resolve(nameData)
  })
}

$(async function() {

  let lists = [];

  function initAutocomplete(list) {
    const thisKey = 'Name'
    $("#name").autocomplete('option', 'source', function(request, response) {
      response(
        list.filter(item => {
          if (item[thisKey].toLowerCase().includes(request.term.toLowerCase())) {
            item.label = item[thisKey]
            return item
          }
        })
      )
    })
  }

  $("#name").autocomplete({
    minLength: 3,
    source: lists,
    focus: function(event, ui) {
      // the "species" is constant - it shouldn't be modified
      $("#company").val(ui.item.Name);
      return false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      // handling n number of fields / columns
      headings.forEach(heading => {
        $('#' + heading).val(ui.item[heading])
      })
      return false;
    }
  });

  // starting data download, processing and usage
  getJSON()
    .then(json => {
      return processRawData(json)
    })
    .then(data => {
      // just so we see what data we are using
      // console.log(data)
      // make the processed data accessible globally
      lists = data
      initAutocomplete(lists)
      initInputs(headings)
    })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
      
  <div class="ui-widget">
    <form id="frm1">
      <label for="name">Name: </label>
      <input id="name"><br /><br />

      <div class="fields"></div>
      <!-- PLEASE NOTE THAT THE OTHER INPUT FIELDS WILL BE ADDED DYNAMICALLY -->
      <button type="button" id="Cal">Button</button>
      <p>
        <output id="total" name="amount" for="calculation">0</output>
      </p>

<div class="chart-gauge">
      <h1 id="percentValue"></h1>
</div> 
      
    </form>
```

Comment: a small gauge is displaying .But no output perhaps.

Comment: Output of form is displayed when we calculate something in form. Fill last three input fields of form with some value and then click button...... I have tried connecting form with Gauge. But it is not working.. :(

Comment: here totalPercent = .75; is fixed that should comming from  textbox having id total

Comment: @LDS, so what should I do?

Comment: totalPercent = parseInt($("#total").val());

Comment: total percent is different friend. Changing it is affecting position of gauge only and not needle :(

Comment: hey friend which value change the gauge that input id send with that otherwise create a hiden field and stored the calculated value for

Comment: var percent is responsible for any change in value of Gauge. Therefore, I have attached arithmetic calculation formula directly with it. But unfortunately, it is not working..

Comment: hey whether calcVal is a function or array and where define look for it may find a solution